# Office add-in - Manifest requirement section not reflected in supported platforms

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-store

We're currently trying to publish an add-in on the office store, but it uses functionality from the 1.9 version of the ExcelApi requirement set. This requirement set is not supported on Excel for OSX 2016 (which is fine, none of our clients are on OSX of any kind). However, when I update my manifest to reflect this requirement, manifest validation (as well as the manifest upload section of the MS partner center) still shows Excel for OSX 2016 as a supported platform, and we've been rejected because our add-in fails testing on that platform. This is what the `Requirements` section of the add-in's manifest looks like:

```
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="CustomFunctionsRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
      <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.9"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

According to this page, Office for OSX 2016 doesn't support ExcelApi above 1.1, and doesn't seem to support the CustomFunctionsRuntime at all, so I'm not sure why it's still considered a valid target: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For assistance on Microsoft Commercial Marketplace, Azure Marketplace, AppSource and Certification issues, please sign-in to Marketplace Publisher Support at https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport and follow the below steps.
 
 · Create a ticket in Partner Center
 · Browse Topics
 · Category: Commercial Marketplace
 · Topic: Certification
 · Sub-Topic: Office Add-in
 · Next step: Review solutions
 · provide issue details

Comment: Done. However this is still a major problem. I feel like I have to be doing something wrong, otherwise this would be a severe bug that would prevent almost any modern add-in from being approved, and I would still appreciate some actual help.